# Type 'Resolver<{ email: string; password: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<IAuthLogin, any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form in NextJS with Typescript,
here's my formhook

```
    const schema = yup.object().shape({
        email: yup.string().email().required(),
        password: yup.string().min(8).max(32).required(),
    });

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm<IAuthLogin>({
        defaultValues: {
            email: '', // Set initial value for email field
            password: '', // Set initial value for password field
        },
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    });
```

Interface

```
export interface IAuthLogin {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    is_admin: boolean;
}
```

The problem is with resolver , my VS code gives me red line under it and says,
[see the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syIKa.png)

how can i assign type to resolver in this case?

i don't really seem to figure out how to assign Type to it,

I looked through react-hook-form , [here](https://react-hook-form.com/ts) , there is one example of resolver type defining,

but in my case i am using yup to create schema, help me fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a type mismatch between the ResolverOptions of yupResolver and your IAuthLogin interface. The ResolverOptions is trying to validate all fields from the form values interface, but your schema only defines validation rules for the email and password fields, not the is_admin field.
Since your schema defines validation rules only for the email and password fields, you should remove the is_admin field from the interface since it's not being validated by the schema. If you are using the is_admin field in your form, you can handle its validation separately if needed.
Alternatively, if is_admin doesn't require validation you can add the is_admin field in the schema without applying any validation rules to it,

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
   email: yup.string().email().required(),
   password: yup.string().min(8).max(32).required(),
   is_admin: yup.boolean(), // This keeps is_admin in the schema without validation rules
})
```

Comment: Thanks Nazrul, looked through my code last night, found the same solution you have mentioned here.